# PostgreSQL - how to insert row (column does not exist)

Tags: postgresql

I would never expect that I would need help with such a banal command:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, field1) VALUES (1, "dfds");
```

And result:

```
column dfds does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO test (id, field1) VALUES (1, "dfds");;
                                                ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 41
```

This is 200% correct SQL. 'dfds' is not any 'column' - this is value.

How to insert row in PGAdmin (GUI)? I click on 'view data' icon and no way to insert row.

Comment: 200% correct is wrong for two reasons. Firstly nothing can be more than 100% correct and secondly you are using double quotes where the SQL standard requires single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String are quoted with `'`:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, field1) VALUES (1, 'dfds');
```

`"` is for identifiers.

Comment: Thank you. How to add row using PGAdmin (GUI)? On mouseOver I have 'Read-only column'. What it means?